# Scrapy - calling spiders as methods from other scripts

Tags: scrapy

I have created this class with `parse()`:

```
class PitchforkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "pitchfork_reissues"
    allowed_domains = ["pitchfork.com"]
    #creates objects for each URL listed here
    start_urls = [
                    "http://pitchfork.com/reviews/best/reissues/?page=1",
                    "http://pitchfork.com/reviews/best/reissues/?page=2",
                    "http://pitchfork.com/reviews/best/reissues/?page=3",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        items = []

        for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="album-artist"]'):
            item = PitchforkItem()
            item['artist'] = sel.xpath('//ul[@class="artist-list"]/li/text()').extract()
            item['reissue'] = sel.xpath('//h2[@class="title"]/text()').extract()
            items.append(item)

        return items
```

**From another script**, I import the `module` where the above `class` belongs:

```
from blogs.spiders.pitchfork_reissues_feed import *
```

and, instantiating the `class`, I try to call `parse()` method:

```
def reissues():

    pitchfork_reissues = PitchforkSpider()
    albums = pitchfork_reissues.parse(response)
    print (albums)
```

but I get the following error:

```
    reissues = pitchfork_reissues.parse(response)
NameError: global name 'response' is not defined
```

Aparently, the `parse()`method requires an instance of `scrapy.http.Response`. 
**How do I create such an instance in the context of this second script, inside `reissues()`?**

Comment: how do you use your `PitchforkSpider` class in the first script?

Comment: @njzk2 what do you mean? could you please be more specific?

Comment: you say `From another script`. I assume you have another script that uses that class successfully?

Comment: @njzk2 the `spider` class is being used successfully if I crawl `pitchfork_reissues`directly. what I intend to do is import `spider` class from another script, with other code and classes.

Comment: did you try what is described in here: https://tryolabs.com/blog/2011/09/27/calling-scrapy-python-script/ ?

Answer (score 0):

```
from scrapy.http import Response

response = Response(body=u'html here')
```

Now I don't think you will be able to crawl this way, as it isn't how Scrapy is supposed to work, but you can still create Response objects

Comment: note my edit. can you please add your answer in the context of the code above?, otherwise it is of no use..I just want to return items crawled into my script.